# How to connect to the server

Tags: android

I am doing multimedia application, Now i am concentrating on connecting my application to server. i want to store all my multimedia files(music and videos) into server. whenever my device is connected to WIFI i want to access all my multimedia files from server. In short i want to access my server through WIFI. can anyone pls guide me how to access this process, also give some useful links to know this process in details.

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
you need to make an http request to the server and then upload the data to it. for this simply create servlets on the server which can read and store the files. whereas on the client part follow the following APIs. [httpclient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html).. do remember to use POST/GET methods for file uploads etc.Hope this helps